# Pivot table OR Where clause in LINQ and SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to achieve a list of rows based on a table using SQL and LINQ. 
The available table is as followed:

```
ID  SName  SValue  LName  LValue  FName  FValue
1   TextS  1.1     null   null    null   null
2    null  null    TextL  2.2     null   null
3    null  null    null   null    TextF  3.3
```

I am trying write a query which can result a list like this:

```
listColumn1  listColumn2
TextS        1.1
TextL        2.2
TextF        3.3
```

Please help with your expert advice.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want this done on the server side using sql? What rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify what RDBMS you are using but if you are using SQL Server 2008+ and you want to perform this in SQL and then use the result you can `UNPIVOT` the data:

```
SELECT x.listColumn1,
  x.listColumn2
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY 
(
    VALUES
        (t.SName, t.SValue),
        (t.LName, t.LValue),
        (t.FName, t.FValue)
) x (listColumn1, listColumn2)
where x.listColumn1 is not null
  and x.listColumn2 is not null
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10a36/4)

Result:

```
| LISTCOLUMN1 | LISTCOLUMN2 |
-----------------------------
|       TextS |         1.1 |
|       TextL |         2.2 |
|       TextF |         3.3 |
```